# Apostles' Tribe Connections

Tags: jesus, apostle

Is there any indication of which tribe each Apostle came from? The Twelve are identified by Jesus in Luke 6:12-16 and Matthew 10:1-4:

> And he called to him his twelve disciples and gave them authority over unclean spirits, to cast them out, and to heal every disease and every affliction. The names of the twelve apostles are these: first, Simon, who is called Peter, and Andrew his brother; James the son of Zebedee, and John his brother; Philip and Bartholomew; Thomas and Matthew the tax collector; James the son of Alphaeus, and Thaddaeus; Simon the Zealot, and Judas Iscariot, who betrayed him.

With the lists of names in these two passages, how would one go about researching the tribal association of each of the Apostles?

Comment: Was the edit acceptable for including this question, reaffirmed closed or under review?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I found the following paragraph at https://bible.org/article/judas

> Judas’ Background

The New Testament does not reveal much about Judas’ family and the environment in which he grew up. His surname was “Iscariot” ( jIskariwvq = t/w”riq] yai = man of Karioth). Most scholars understand it to refer to the place of his origin, from Kerioth, in southern Judaea (Matthew 10:4; 26:14; John 6:71; 12:4; 13:2,26; 14:22).2 The best estimation today would be to identify Kerioth with Kerioth-hezron (Joshua 15:25), which is about 15 miles south of Hebron. Judas was, then, the only apostle from Judea; the rest were from Galilee. All we know of his family is that his father’s name was Simon (John 6:71).

There is also a discussion of this topic here:

http://forums.swordsearcher.com/threads/tribes-of-the-12-disciples.953/

It would be worth scrolling down to find the summary from the person who originally posted the question, rather than read through the whole discussion.  (It was at the bottom of the first page in my browser.)

In summary, like the article above, he too said that Judas was likely identified with the tribe of Judah, while the others were all Galileans.  He went on to say that they were likely all Benjamites, because mostly Benjamites populated the region of the sea of Galilee, where Jesus was raised and began His ministry. He gives Scripture references to support his inferences.

Comment: Welcome to BH.SE! Please [take the tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a feel for how the site functions. It would be more appropriate for you to add to your answer a short summary of how that forum post addresses the question here.